# Скло́нятся колени или склоня́тся?

Tags: грамотная-речь, орфоэпия, глаголы

Можно ли ставить ударение на первый слог в слове "склонятся"?
Контекст такой: "и все колени скло́нятся пред Именем Его"(Божьим).
Это перевод песни, таким образом хорошо текст на музыку ложится.

Comment: Если в песне, то можно, хоть склонятьсЯ.

Answer (score 2):

*Можно ли ставить ударение на первый слог в слове "склонятся"?*
**Можно!**

Заглянем в печатные словари:

• склони́ться, -оню́сь, -о́нишься (Орфографический СРЯ под ред. С. И. Ожегова и А. Б. Шапиро, АН СССР, Институт языкознания, 110 000 слов, 1957) [= **скло́нятся**];

• склони́ть(ся), склоню́(сь), скло́нишь(ся) (Словарь ударений для работников радио и телевидения, Ф. Л. Агеенко и М. В. Зарва, под ред. Д. Э. Розенталя, около 63 000 слов, 1967)
[= **скло́нятся**];

• склони́ться, склоню́сь, скло́нится и *доп.* склони́тся (Орфоэпический СРЯ под ред. Р. И. Аванесова, АН СССР, Институт русского языка, 65 000 слов, 1989) [= **скло́нятся** и *допустимо* **склоня́тся**];

• склони́ть(ся), -оню́(сь), -о́ни́т(ся) (Орфографический СРЯ, В. В. Бурцева, более 25 000 слов, 2003) [= **скло́нятся** и **склоня́тся**].

А уж в сети посмотрите сами:
словари на ["Грамоте"](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F);
словари на ["academic.ru"](https://diffc_ru.academic.ru/8024/%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F).